# Detect header delimiters importing a csv file using pandas read_csv

Tags: python, file, csv, pandas

Here we go again.

Hi, I'm trying to detect an error in a CSV file.

The file should look as follows

```
    goodfile.csv

    "COL_A","COL_B","COL_C","COL_D"
    "ROW1COLA","ROW1COLB","ROW1COLC","ROW1COLD"
    "ROW2COLA","ROW2COLB","ROW2COLC","ROW2COLD"
    "ROW3COLA","ROW3COLB","ROW3COLC","ROW3COLD"
    "ROW4COLA","ROW4COLB","ROW4COLC","ROW4COLD"
    "ROW5COLA","ROW5COLB","ROW5COLC","ROW5COLD"
    "ROW6COLA","ROW6COLB","ROW6COLC","ROW6COLD"
    "ROW7COLA","ROW7COLB","ROW7COLC","ROW7COLD"
```

But the file I have is actually

```
    brokenfile.csv

    "COL_A","COL_B",COL C,"COL_D"
    "ROW1COLA","ROW1COLB","ROW1COLC","ROW1COLD"
    "ROW2COLA","ROW2COLB","ROW2COLC","ROW2COLD"
    "ROW3COLA","ROW3COLB","ROW3COLC","ROW3COLD"
    "ROW4COLA","ROW4COLB","ROW4COLC","ROW4COLD"
    "ROW5COLA","ROW5COLB","ROW5COLC","ROW5COLD"
    "ROW6COLA","ROW6COLB","ROW6COLC","ROW6COLD"
    "ROW7COLA","ROW7COLB","ROW7COLC","ROW7COLD"
```

When I import the two files with pandas

```
    data = pd.read_csv('goodfile.csv')
    data = pd.read_csv('brokenfile.csv')
```

I get the same result

```
    data

          COL_A     COL_B     COL_C     COL_D
    0  ROW1COLA  ROW1COLB  ROW1COLC  ROW1COLD
    1  ROW2COLA  ROW2COLB  ROW2COLC  ROW2COLD
    2  ROW3COLA  ROW3COLB  ROW3COLC  ROW3COLD
    3  ROW4COLA  ROW4COLB  ROW4COLC  ROW4COLD
    4  ROW5COLA  ROW5COLB  ROW5COLC  ROW5COLD
    5  ROW6COLA  ROW6COLB  ROW6COLC  ROW6COLD
    6  ROW7COLA  ROW7COLB  ROW7COLC  ROW7COLD
```

Anyway, what I want is to detect the error in the second file "brokenfile.csv" that currently lacks "" between the header COL_C

Comment: You can pass `quoting = 3` to `read_csv` so pandas will not remove those characters but both files are valid csv files. I don't think there is any reason for pandas to raise an error.

Comment: Is your goal only to detect when headers lack double quotes? What about single quotes? Any other "errors" that should be detected? Also, you shouldn't "get the same result" - one data should have `COL_C` and another `COL C`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can detect missing `"` in columns of `DataFrame` with [`str.contains`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.contains.html) and [`boolean indexing`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#boolean-indexing) with inverted `boolean array` by `~`:

```
import pandas as pd
import io

temp=u'''"COL_A","COL_B",COL C,"COL_D"
"ROW1COLA","ROW1COLB","ROW1COLC","ROW1COLD"
"ROW2COLA","ROW2COLB","ROW2COLC","ROW2COLD"
"ROW3COLA","ROW3COLB","ROW3COLC","ROW3COLD"
"ROW4COLA","ROW4COLB","ROW4COLC","ROW4COLD"
"ROW5COLA","ROW5COLB","ROW5COLC","ROW5COLD"
"ROW6COLA","ROW6COLB","ROW6COLC","ROW6COLD"
"ROW7COLA","ROW7COLB","ROW7COLC","ROW7COLD"'''
#after testing replace io.StringIO(temp) to filename
df = pd.read_csv(io.StringIO(temp), quoting = 3)
print df
      "COL_A"     "COL_B"       COL C     "COL_D"
0  "ROW1COLA"  "ROW1COLB"  "ROW1COLC"  "ROW1COLD"
1  "ROW2COLA"  "ROW2COLB"  "ROW2COLC"  "ROW2COLD"
2  "ROW3COLA"  "ROW3COLB"  "ROW3COLC"  "ROW3COLD"
3  "ROW4COLA"  "ROW4COLB"  "ROW4COLC"  "ROW4COLD"
4  "ROW5COLA"  "ROW5COLB"  "ROW5COLC"  "ROW5COLD"
5  "ROW6COLA"  "ROW6COLB"  "ROW6COLC"  "ROW6COLD"
6  "ROW7COLA"  "ROW7COLB"  "ROW7COLC"  "ROW7COLD"

print df.columns
Index([u'"COL_A"', u'"COL_B"', u'COL C', u'"COL_D"'], dtype='object')

print df.columns.str.contains('"')
[ True  True False  True]

print ~df.columns.str.contains('"')
[False False  True False]

print df.columns[~df.columns.str.contains('"')]
Index([u'COL C'], dtype='object')
```

Comment: Wow, that was great, i have to learn so many things to be like you. Thank you.

Comment: Yes, you saved me 2 times in one day. Thank you. Where i can learn more of this topic? i'm starting as freelancer and i used to think that know python programming but i see that i have a lot of thing to learn. Sorry if my english isn't perfect. Greetings from Venezuela!

Comment: Greetings from Slovakia. :) I think [`pandas`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/index.html) docs is wonderfull. There is a lot samples. And my experience - the best learning is trying to answer to StackOverflow.

Answer (score 0):

Pandas is trying to be smart about recognising data types when reading in data. This is exactly what's happening in the case you're describing, `COL_C` and `"COL_C"` are both parsed as strings really.

In short, there is no error to detect! At least pandas will not produce an error in cases like this.

What you could do, if you wanted to detect missing quotes in header, you could try to read in the first line in a more "traditional" pythonic way and make your own conclusions from there:

```
>>> with open('filename') as f:
        lines = f.readlines()
        ....
```

Comment: Yes, i know that pandas is really smart. But in writing a program and i want to warn the user that missing "" in the header.

Comment: Well, as far as pandas is concerned, there is no error here. I cannot see how you can pandas to produce some kind of error/warning in cases like this. See updated answer.